# backlight reading from wrong file Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laptop, lenovo, backlight

In `/sys/class/backlight/` I have to folders, `ideapad` and `intel_backlight`. After some unidentifiable event, the brightness controls stopped working. After a lot of reading the internet, I identified the problem: the physical brightness buttons and the brightness control were all changing the value of `intel_backlight/brightness` while the screen itself read `ideapad/brightness` to decide what to do. I edited the file manually (`echo 16 | sudo tee ideapad/brightness`), but the usual controls still don't work. How could I a) get the computer to read from the `intel_backlight` or alternatively, b) how could I get the computer to change the values of `ideapad` instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ideapad, but if it's just a text file you can write a script  to change its value and bind it to the key in settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts

Comment: try this
#!/bin/bash

brightnessFile="IDEAPADTHING"
currentBrightness=$(cat $brightnessFile)
currentBrightness="$(($currentBrightness + 1))"
echo -n "$currentBrightness" > "$brightnessFile" 

That didn't paste right so it's here too https://pastebin.com/CjqptRa5